# git cluster client setup. Push to Server A...replicate to server B...Clone server B

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I would like to create a Git read/write cluster.
That is clear how can I make it on server side. How replicate the commits from Server A to server B.

I try to search how can I set on client side to clone and read from server B and push/commit to server A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't directly do this when cloning, but you can change the remote that is created to use different URIs through the `set-url` command and the `--push` option:

```
git clone <ServerB> # Create a clone from ServerB
git remote set-url --push origin <ServerA> # Set the push URI of the default remote to ServerA
```

That way, it will always fetch from ServerB, but push to ServerA (of course only when using the defined remote)

Comment: Thanks Tim.Can I automate the remote change on client side?

Comment: Not that I would know of, unless there is a clone flag that I haven't found yet.